# Is there a way for me to flash my code on a STM32F4 board via UART bridge?

Tags: serial-port, embedded, stm32, uart, bootloader

So, I have a STM32f407vet6 board and a Silicon Labs cp210x USB to UART bridge.
Is there a way for me to flash my project onto the board using the bridge?

Preferably I would like to use it with µVision to flash a project with FreeRTOS. I had trouble finding the answer since the only guides online recommend I use ST-Link or similar programmers, and most IDE-s show them as the only option.

Comment: I would advice to buy SWD debug probe if you want to code something. UART bootloader is used to load/update the images which are already in the production stage. The cheapest ones cost about $3-4.

Comment: `and most IDE-s show them as the only option` - it is logical. I do not think that anyone sane will try to write any software without having the debug probe. Probes are very cheap and even you can easily convert the BLUE PILL board ($1.6) into the SWD/JTAG DAP debug probe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

STM32F407VET6 describes a chip not a *board*, and as such it is not possible to tell whether you can do it with your board. You have to be able to assert the boot pins to boot from *system memory*, which initiates the bootloader in mask ROM. Using that it is possible to program the flash memory via USART1 (PA9/PA10), USART3 (PC10/PC11 or PB10/PB11), CAN2 (PB5/PB13), and USB
OTG FS in Device mode (PA11/PA12) through DFU (device firmware upgrade).

So whether it is possible depends on your board design and whether the boot pins can be set appropriately and whether either UART1 or UART3 are available on the specified pins.

Even then you are, unlikely to find such support in your IDE since the IDE's main purpose is development and debugging, while the built-in bootloader is suitable only for programming and is intended for in-field update rather then development.  For any serious development you will want a JTAG or SWI device such as an ST-Link.  Many low cost development boards from ST include an ST-Link integrated on the board, with a header to support connection to other boards without one.

There is an article on loading STM32F4 devices over UART at http://stm32f4-discovery.net/2014/09/program-stm32f4-with-uart/

Comment: This actually helps me alot. The Board I'm using has an ICSP port. So without a dedicated programmer like the ST-Link i presume i can only perform an ICSP rather than perform full development like altering clock speeds and changing the operating system?

Comment: @Pisoj61 : Not at all; the PLL is configured in software - the Keil ARM MDK provides start-up code that does that, and you can modify it - you don't need JTAG programming for that, and an RTOS is simply a statically linked library.  Everything - start-up code, RTOS and application code is included in the binary you build in the IDE - you simply set the linker options to create a .hex format binary and you can then use that to program the flash.  What you cannot do is run the debugger and set breakpoints, inspect memory and single-step the code for example.

Comment: ICSP is a term used for Microchip PIC parts - it is not clear what this port in on your board.

Comment: You also cannot unlock a chip with RDP enabled without JTAG/SWI.  Do not secure the chip if you ever want to re-program it again.

Comment: Built the project and flashed it using the STM Flash Loader via bridge, works like a charm. I understand the whole process a lot better now, can't thank you enough.